# Event machine for parallel api requests

Tags: ruby, api, caching, foursquare, eventmachine

I'm creating an application which uses venues and categories from Foursquare. In order to speed up some algorithms and avoid too much api calls to Foursquare I decided to prefetch some data from Foursquare (using its API) and store it on my end in mongodb database.

In the current implementation of the prefetching algorithm in order to speed up the process I'm performing parallel requests to Foursquare using simple ruby's threading mechanism, for example:

```
threads = []
venue_ids.each do |venue_id|
  threads << Thread.new
    data = fetch_venue_from_foursquare(venue_id)
    do_something_with(data)
  end
end
threads.join
```

Generally this approach works but I have several problems with errors handling and sometimes it could just stop and never end.

How can I improve this approach?
Is it possible to use eventmachine in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

:-)

Check out [em-synchrony](http://www.igvita.com/2010/03/22/untangling-evented-code-with-ruby-fibers/).